# Can I modify likert-type questions with different amount of points to same quantify of points?

Tags: survey

I am on the level of launching my questionnaire for my master paper, but am concerned about my questions. Almost 80% of my questions are 7 point likert-type format, other 20% are 5 point likert-type. I have adapted all the scales from the previous similar researches, therefore, the quantity of points were adapted exactly as they were in source papers. However, I am concerned about my future data analysis. I have heard that analyzing the data, in connection with each other, gathered with different pointed likert-type questions will be difficult and complicated.

Therefore, I wanted to ask, if it is up to me to change the points and modify 5 point likert-type questions to 7 points? is it permitted to do so?

To note, all of them ranges from "Completely disagree" to "Completely agree"

Comment: This sounds like a question better directed to your thesis advisor. That said, do I imagine that changing the number of scale points used by a psychometric instrument would destroy the validity of the construct being measured? Nope, not a chance. IMHO, make the changes and note it in your "technical" or methodological writeup.

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of this one... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181262/can-i-modify-likert-type-questions-with-different-amount-of-points-to-same-quant

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the questionnaire has not been administered yet. If so, then there is scope for changing the questions. The issue then becomes a trade-off between (a) following what previous researchers did exactly and (b) using similar scales for consistency and simplicity within your own project.

Comment: Djohnson, 
Thus, as I understood, I can directly change from 5 point to 7 seven points? I will surely mention it in methodological part.


Nick Cox,
Nope, questionnaire hasn't been launched yet.
Actually, that's the point I want to know. all those 7 point as well as 5 point questions were directly adapted from original paper.
But to make it easier for data analysis, I thought if I am allowed to change the points from 5 to 7.thus in case of your B) version, am I allowed to use some other researchers scales and modify it myself to adapt to my needs, even though I won't change the main content

Comment: Who is allowing or forbidding here? If this were my problem I would prefer **using 5 point scales consistently**, partly because I find 7 point scales over-precise, but that's more a matter of experience in analysis of data and in answering questionnaires, not because I profess any specific psychometric expertise. The key point here is that your questionnaire design should be informed by your plans on how you will analyse the data.

Comment: Therefore, you mean, that it is fully up to me if I change it or not?
cause I thought that there might be some regulation about modifying the original scales, thus I'd face some problems from committee.
By the way, I was thinking about converting all of them to 5 point liker-style questions as, coming from the fact that my questionnaire is quite big, it will be easier for respondent to answer the questions, there I will get more answers. I have read somewhere and it's logically right that 7 point scale requires more effort to answer from respondents thatn 5 point.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't possibly predict, or advise on, what your committee might or might not say or on what "regulations" might apply to you. Even the collective wisdom of Cross Validated contributors can't possibly be taken as some absolute Statistical Truth or Correct Way.

Comment: yeah, I fully understand that. but I thought there should be some general regulation or rule about it. Seems I am mistaken

Comment: The only rule here that I can see is a rule of thumb that answers to questions asked in different ways can't so easily be compared as questions asked in similar ways. That is important.